# Why does tsquery in postgres exclude the letter 't'?

Tags: postgresql, tsvector

When I run the following statement in postgres it removes the letter 't' from the resulting tsquery:

Statement: `select websearch_to_tsquery('english', 'xtp t');`

Result: `xtp`

Same result with underscore separating:

Statement: `select websearch_to_tsquery('english', 'xtp_t');`

Result: `xtp`

**However, if I substitute the 't' for any other letter I get the expected result:**

Statement: `select websearch_to_tsquery('english', 'xtp_l');`

Result: `'xtp' <-> 'l'`

Why does the letter 't' get removed from the result of the original query?

Comment: see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/textsearch-controls.html ; basically the  normalisation removes the single 't' as its already in 'xtp' - you can see in SELECT to_tsvector('xtp_l');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not any other letter.  i, a, s, and t are considered stop words in English.  'I' and 'a' actually are very common words, s and t are presumably included because they occur in contractions and possessives, like "I can't stand dog's slobbery toys"